# Cannot insert into temp table. why?

Tags: sql-server-2008

Below is the original query

```
DECLARE @categoryKeys VARCHAR(max),
        @startPromos INT,
        @countPromos INT,
        @promoKey INT,
        @parse VARCHAR(max),
        @final VARCHAR(max),
        @branch_code VARCHAR(max)

CREATE TABLE #NewperBranch
(
    id INT,
    promoKey INT,
    Branch VARCHAR(50),
    Combo VARCHAR(60),
    Category VARCHAR(50),
    Item VARCHAR(60)
) 

--INSERT INTO #NewperBranch
--SELECT
SELECT  promo_key FROM dbo.branch_promos WHERE branch_lookup_key = 25

SELECT @countPromos = COUNT(*) from #NewperBranch
SET @startPromos = 1
WHILE @startPromos <= @countPromos

SELECT @branch_code = branch_code FROM dbo.branches WHERE lookup_key = @promoKey
SELECT @promoKey = promoKey FROM #NewperBranch WHERE id = @startPromos
SELECT @categoryKeys = p.category_keys FROM dbo.promos p WHERE [key] = @promoKey    

 -- INSERT INTO #NewperBranch
-- 0,
--@promoKey,
--@branch_code,
--'',
--'',
--''

INSERT INTO #NewperBranch
    SELECT npb.id,-- AS 'id',
           p.[key],-- AS 'promoKey',
           b.branch_code,-- AS 'Branch',
           p.name,-- AS 'Combo',
           c.name,-- AS 'Category',
           i.name --AS 'Item'
    FROM items i 
    INNER JOIN dbo.branches b ON i.category_key = b.lookup_key
    INNER JOIN dbo.categories c ON i.category_key = c.[key]  
    INNER JOIN dbo.promos p ON p.[key] = @promoKey
    INNER JOIN #NewperBranch npb ON npb.id = npb.id
    WHERE category_key IN (SELECT [key] FROM dbo.categories
    WHERE [key] IN (SELECT * FROM dbo.parse_comma_delimited_string(@categoryKeys)))
    SET @startPromos = @startPromos + 1

SELECT * FROM #NewperBranch
DROP TABLE #NewperBranch
```

Above is original query..
 Need to insert the results to the temp table but it keeps showing me blank
 results.Is this because of inner joining?

Comment: What is intended by `INNER JOIN #NewperBranch npb ON npb.id = npb.id`? If the table is newly created, it will have no data.

Comment: fast response as always. Thank you sir

Comment: but i pass the values into the temp table. and i already created the table ..

Comment: what error do u get?

Comment: Yes the inner join is the problem, the table should contain some values which fulfils query otherwise the query will return only blank. You should change the way of querying i.e., alter the query.

Comment: @SHEKHARSHETE i created the table and i select the value to insert it in temp..  my error is it shows no results..

Comment: @KarthikAMR hi sir my table contain values.. but it show no results again..

Comment: @KarthikAMR i have now results just fixed the joining .. thank u all

Comment: @KarthikAMR hi one more question why shows no results when i added  this ' WHERE'

Comment: I solved it by creating another temp table :D ty guys